# mailer yii2 500 error на хостинге

Tags: php, yii2, sendmail

Добрый день, прошу пнуть на нужный материал или мысль. Тема такая, что сайт на хостинге и выполнены настройки согласно документации хоста. Парадокс в том, что при использовании обычной функции php mail() - письмо замечательно отправляется, а при использовании swiftmailer - 500 ошибка.
Настройки:

```
'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'p123456.mail.ihc.ru',
            'username' => 'support@eurasiatt.com',
            'password' => '*********',
            'port' => '465',
            'encryption' => 'tls',
        ],
        'useFileTransport' => false,
    ],
```

Контроллер:

```
Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
        ->setTo('mymail@gmail.com')
        ->setSubject('Тема сообщения')
        ->setTextBody('Текст сообщения')
        ->setHtmlBody('<b>текст сообщения в формате HTML</b>')
        ->send();
```

Comment: А логи что говорят?

Comment: getmypid - корень бед, есть ли альтернатива? Исключать его из swiftmailer?

Comment: Замените на mt_rand(0, 32000) (из http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24756783/disabled-getmypid-on-shared-host)

Comment: Спасибо, теперь Cannot send message without a sender address

Comment: Ну так документацию курите, как вот тут - https://toster.ru/q/115733 - вам ещё надо присобачить ->setFrom ;)

Comment: Не за что, если вам помогли мои советы в разрешении вопроса - поставьте мой ответ внизу как подошедший.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге нужно заменить getmypid на mt_rand и добавить ->setFrom для почты отправителя.